# How do you set ApiController.User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In my apicontroller I use base.user to identify the authenticated user to use in a lookup.  Now I am writing a unit test for this but I cannot figure out how to mock apicontroller.user.  Do I need to create a request and set the user there?  Or is there another way to set the controller.user?

Here is my controller; I have already mocked repository and membershipservice.

```
[Authorize]
public class DocumentController : ApiController
{
    DocumentRepository _repository;
    IStaticMembershipService _membership;

    public IEnumerable<Document> GetDocuments()
    {
        MembershipUser userAccount = _membership.GetUser(base.User);
        IEnumerable<Document> docs = null;

        if (userAccount != null)
        {
            docs = _repository.GetDocumentsByUserId(
                (Guid) userAccount.ProviderUserKey);
        }

        return docs;
    }
```

Here is my unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class DocumentControllerWebService
{
    private DocumentsContext _context;
    private DocumentRepository _repository;
    private DocumentController _controller;
    private FakeMembershipService _membership;
    private TestContext testContextInstance;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void MyTestInitialize()
    {
        // Create a context with a fake data set provider
        _context = new DocumentsContext(new FakeDbSetProvider());
        _repository = new DocumentRepository(_context);
        _membership = new FakeMembershipService();
        _controller = new DocumentController(_repository, _membership);
    }

    public void GetDocumentsTest()
    {
        string userName = "someUser";
        MembershipUser userAccount = _membership.GetUser(userName);
        Guid userId = (Guid) userAccount.ProviderUserKey;
        Guid anotherUserId = Guid.NewGuid();

        // Get some dummy data and insert it into the fake repository
        List<Document> forms = DocumentDummyData.GetListOfDummyData(
            userId, anotherUserId);
        forms.ForEach(f => _repository.InsertDocument(f));

        // I would like to do this but User is readonly
        _controller.User = userName;

        List<Document> docs = _controller.GetDocuments().ToList();
        foreach (Document expected in forms.Where(d => d.UserId == userId))
        {
            Document actual = docs.Where(
                d => d.DocumentID == expected.DocumentID).FirstOrDefault();
            Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected.DocumentID, actual.DocumentID);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the user from http Request then you'll want to look at a way of mocking that out.  Thankfully that has been done many times.  A good place to start would be to read this

http://www.codethinked.com/post/2008/12/04/Using-SystemWebAbstractions-in-Your-WebForms-Apps.aspx

To summarize what I did which followed this, a hanselman blog and some trial and error:

In your ApiController add this to your constructor

```
HttpContextWrapper = HttpContextFactory.GetHttpContext();
```

The factory is this

```
public static class HttpContextFactory
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static HttpContextBase _mockHttpContext;
    public static void SetHttpContext(HttpContextBase httpContextBase)
    {
        _mockHttpContext = httpContextBase;
    }

    public static HttpContextBase GetHttpContext()
    {
        if (_mockHttpContext != null)
        {
            return _mockHttpContext;
        }

        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now you have a seam into which you can insert your mock request, response, session, etc.

```
HttpContextBase httpContext = HttpMocks.HttpContext();
HttpContextFactory.SetHttpContext(httpContext);
```

Finally here is a fairly fully mocked context that I use

```
public class HttpMocks
{
    public static HttpContextBase HttpContext()
    {
        var context = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
        context.Stub(r => r.Request).Return(HttpRequest());
        context.Stub(r => r.Response).Return(HttpResponse());
        context.Stub(r => r.Session).Return(HttpSession());
        context.Stub(r => r.Server).Return(HttpServer());
        return context;
    }

    private static HttpServerUtilityBase HttpServer()
    {
        var httpServer = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
        httpServer.Stub(r => r.MapPath("")).IgnoreArguments().Return("");
        return httpServer;
    }

    private static HttpResponseBase HttpResponse()
    {
        var httpResponse = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var cookies = new HttpCookieCollection {new HttpCookie("UserContext")};
        httpResponse.Stub(r => r.Cookies).Return(cookies);

        Func<string, string> returnWhatWasPassed = x => x;
        httpResponse.Stub(r => r.ApplyAppPathModifier(""))
            .IgnoreArguments().Do(returnWhatWasPassed);

        return httpResponse;
    }

    public static HttpRequestBase HttpRequest()
    {
        var httpRequest = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var cookies = new HttpCookieCollection
        {
            new HttpCookie("UserContext")
        };
        httpRequest.Stub(r => r.Cookies).Return(cookies);

        var parameters = new NameValueCollection
        {
            { "id", "277" },
            { "binderId", "277" }
        };
        httpRequest.Stub(r => r.Params).Return(parameters);
        httpRequest.Stub(r => r.ApplicationPath).Return("/");
        httpRequest.Stub(r => r.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath)
            .Return("~/");
        httpRequest.Stub(r => r.PathInfo).Return("");

        var serverVariables = new NameValueCollection();
        httpRequest.Stub(r => r.ServerVariables).Return(serverVariables);

        return httpRequest;
    }

    public static HttpSessionStateBase HttpSession()
    {
        var s =  new FakeSessionState();
        s["mocking"] = "true";
        return s;
    }
}
```

this makes for a rather long answer but let us know if you need more detail on anything, you can probably ignore fake session for now.

Comment: Thank you I will review the article in the link.  I will also see if I can implement some of your code above.  And yes I shouldn't need the session mocked.